# Export data modified after given date

Tags: export, mysql

I have a database where each table has two columns that indicate when a table row has been created (`gen_date`) or modified (`mod_date`).

I would like to export this complete database (structure) but would like to include only the data modified after a given date.

At the moment I use mysqldump to export the data:

```
mysqldump --user=username --password=password mydatabase
```

This exports all data and the table definitions.

**Question:** Is it possible to export only data with `mod_date` > some given date?

I was thinking about "cloning" the database and then delete all outdated data and use mysqldump to export the remaining data.

Example of a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `brand` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `brand` tinytext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `gen_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `mod_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

mysqldump --user=username --password=password mydatabase mytable --no_create_info --where mod_date >= '2016-03-01' > mytable.sql

Comment: Wow, didn't know this option exists. Will test this asap.

Comment: It should work, if not upload some sample data and I can take another look.